# How to use the control key in VM Ware?

Tags: vmware-fusion

When I use the control key and I click with the left mouse button, it behaves like the right mouse button. I don't want this, I want to select multiple files when I hol the control key.

I've tried [this](http://blogs.vmware.com/teamfusion/2008/11/tip-control-cli.html) but it doesn't work. I've tried to uncheck that box and I have tried to assign a new combination, but both doesn't work.

Does someone know how I can use my control key in Windows? I am using VM Ware Fusion 6.0.1

Edit:
I am using OS X 10.8.4. The Windows version I have installed in my VM is Windows 8. I'm using a USB mouse with two buttons and a scroll wheel.

Comment: @techie007: VMWare Fusion runs on Mac only. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Fusion

Comment: @techie007 I've updated my post. Why not just use right mouse button? Because then I can't select many files in explorer (for example).

Comment: @razumny While I'm aware of that, there are many versions of OS X.  Knowing exactly which one, as well as editions and versions of the guest and VMware software might help people formulate an accurate answer.

Comment: @Martijn: Are you able to select multiple files using Ctrl+Option?

Comment: @martijn Gotcha!  So Right-click does work as right-click, but Ctrl-left-click works as right-click as well.

Comment: @techie007 That's correct. Now, I don't want Ctrl-left-click not to behave like a right-click.

Comment: @razumny Yes, when I use ctrl-CMD then I can select multiple files. I'd like to use just the control key..

Comment: @Martijn: Understood. Does Crl+Option work as you want it to, though? I ask, because that is the alternative suggested here: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1001675

Comment: Just to be clear; the "Option" key is NOT the CMD key, but rather the Alt key.

Comment: @razumny No, that doesn't work. However, contrl-option does work, also does ctrl-cmd

Comment: @Martijn: So, both Ctrl+Option and Ctrl+CMD work fine - is that a fair assessment? Have you tried installing another OS to see if you have the same behaviour there?

Comment: I find it annoying to use a key combination for a key I very often use. I can't install another OS because this Apple is from my work.

Comment: I can see I may have been a bit unclear. I was not intending to suggest you install a different OS than Mac OS X. I was suggesting that you install e.g. a Linux Distro such as Ubuntu to VMWare Fusion.

Answer (score 6):

Holding down CTRL + OPTION together and left clicking will do this.